# How to get the max column values count

Tags: python, pandas

test dataframe is below

```
test=pd.DataFrame({'item_name':['Steak Salad Bowl','Steak Salad Bowl','Barbacoa Salad Bowl','Meat Salad Bowl'],'item_price':[9.39,9.39,9.19,9.39]})

grps = [grp for _, grp in test.groupby('item_name', sort=False)]
print(grps[0],grps[0].shape[0])
```

My Expected out

```
item_name            count
Steak Salad Bowl     2
Meat Salad Bowl      1
```

Comment: Step 1. Find the max of item_price Step 2: Filter rows that are equal to the max value, Step 3: Call value_counts() on the item_name result. Doesn't seem like you've made any attempts, can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering by `max` values, then [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and for `DataFrame` [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (test.loc[test['item_price'].eq(test['item_price'].max()), 'item_name']
          .value_counts()
          .rename_axis('item_name')
          .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)

          item_name  count
0  Steak Salad Bowl      2
1   Meat Salad Bowl      1
```

Or for count use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = (test[test['item_price'].eq(test['item_price'].max())]
          .groupby('item_name')
          .size()
          .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)
          item_name  count
0   Meat Salad Bowl      1
1  Steak Salad Bowl      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `nlargest(n)`:

```py
test.nlargest(1, columns='item_price', keep='all')['item_name'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```py
Steak Salad Bowl    2
Meat Salad Bowl     1
Name: item_name, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Using value_counts() and head() and reset_index() and rename()

```
pd.DataFrame(test['item_name'].value_counts().head(2).reset_index().rename(columns = {'index': 'item_name', 'item_name' : 'count'}))
```

Output

```
             item_name  count
0     Steak Salad Bowl      2
1  Barbacoa Salad Bowl      1
```